# Ответ с сервера приходит в виде HTML, а не JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, vue.js, nuxt.js

Моя задача - авторизация пользователя, при отправке данных через fetch я получаю HTML, а не JSON

**Vue + Nuxt**

```
methods: {
 async sendData() {
  try {
    const values = { name: 'Alex', password: 123456 };
    const res = await this.$store.dispatch('auth/login', values);

    console.log(await res);
  } catch(err) {
    throw err;
  }
 }
}
```

**Vuex**

```js
export const actions = {
  async login({}, data) {
    try {
      const res = await fetch('/auth/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      });

      return await res.json();
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
}
```

**Node.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const authRouter = require('./routes/auth');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('auth', authRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

**Роутер auth.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const { name, password } = req.body;

  return res.json({
    password,
    name
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: ну и что же в это html написано то?

Comment: @ArchDemon в html страница авторизации, с которой я отправил post запрос

Comment: А Вы не желаете подключаться куда-нибудь на сервер?) `fetch('/auth/login' ...)` приведет Вас на Ваш же клиент. Или укажите полный адрес, или укажите `baseUrl` (не знаю как это в fetch делается, но в том же axios лоика такая)

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar по-моему так и так должно работать, но я все-равно попробовал и ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, она заключалась в том, что не было поставлено слэша "/", когда я использовал роутер

```js
app.use('/auth', authRouter);
```